Numbers in correct order
How many 7's must replace the question mark in order for this sequence of numbers to make sense? Explain your reasoning.

    11111
    222222
    33333
    444444
    55555
    66666
      ?
    888888
    99999


No calculations or knowledge (except trivial knowledge) required.

The answer is

 7777777

Because what we are dealing here is the

 Sequence of ordinal numbers: FIRST,SECOND,THIRD,FOURTH,FIFTH,SIXTH,(SEVENTH),EIGHTH,NINTH…

It is represented by

 Each line where the letters of each of these is ‘hidden’ by its corresponding cardinal: FIRST has 5 letters so 5 1s, SECOND has 6 so 6 2s, THIRD has 5 letters so 5 3s, FOURTH has 6 letters so 6 4s and so on…
 


Yes this is correct!
